# How to make multiple calls in one page with SWR nextjs hook?

Tags: promise, fetch, next.js, endpoint, swr

I'd like to fetch 3 endpoints for one page, I'm using the SWR hook from next.js as I need to get it from the client side.
The [documentation](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/conditional-fetching) doesn't help me as I have variables for the url in an other file. I'm new to this. Here is what I have and working well with just one endpoint:

**data.ts**

```ts
const fetcher = (url: string) => fetch(url).then((response) => response.json())

const getData = (endpoint: string) => {
  try {
    const { data, error } = useSWR(`${ENDPOINTS_URL}${endpoint}`, fetcher)
    return { data, error }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error:', error)
    throw error
  }
}

export const getData1 = () => getData(`endpoint1`)
export const getData2 = () => getData(`endpoint2`)
export const getData3 = () => getData(`endpoint3`)
```

And this is where I call them:

**index.tsx**

```ts
const { data, error } = getData1()
  if (error) return <div>failed to load</div>
  if (!data) return <div>loading...</div>
```

Comment: Is it not enough good to call `useSWR` 3 times? Is there what you want to else?

Comment: Yes but how can call useSWR 3 times, that's my issue there.  Staying as DRY as possible. I don't succeed to solve this
```const { data: data1, error } = getData1()```
```const { data: data2, error } = getData2()```
This doesn't work..

Comment: Wait, you reassign `error`. This might cause it? I'm not sure yet because I have not examined in detail.

Comment: What about using components?

Answer (score 9):

Okay I got it!
Here is my solution (without the `error`):

data.ts

```
const getData = (endpoint: string) => {
  try {
    const { data } = useSWR(`${ENDPOINTS_URL}${endpoint}`, fetcher)
    return { data: data }
//...
}

export const getData1 = () => getData(`endpoint1`)
```

index.tsx

```
const { data: name1 } = getData1()
const { data: name2 } = getData2()
```

et voilà!
I hope it can help someone in the future :)

Comment: This breaks the rules of hooks... no? https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions